# Add a marker to geo URI in phonegap app

Tags: google-maps, cordova

I want to add a marker to the latitude and longitude i feed to geo uri in my html.
I searched previous asked questions but didnt find a solution to this problem. any help will be appreciated. I want to complete this task without using any plugin.

```
 <a  class="button-green button-green--large" href="geo:19.07,72.99">Locate</a>
```

when i press the above locate button (anchor tag) Google maps opens up at latitude and longitude specified without the marker...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try following code:

`<a class="button-green button-green--large" href="geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)">Locate</a>`

Change the `lat` and `long` as you wish.

Comment: @bijang any idea how to add multiple marker in same scenario ??

Comment: @bjiang where did you find about **?q** paremeter. Any link to documentation?

Comment: Only doc I found https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5870